# ASP.NET MVC 4 State of Uploaded File

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Ninject for dependency injection and I'm trying to bind an uploaded file to a graphics handler that is going to resize image and other stuff.

I also have a model that has an `HttpPostedFileBase` field for the uploaded file. The problem is, how can I use an uploaded file before it gets to the controller?

I tried with `Application_BeginRequest()` method in global.asax like this...

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["UploadedFile"]
```

but this code returns null in `Application_BeginRequest()`, but inside a controller in the model, the uploaded file is there.

I now there are mods in IIS that forbid access of the HttpContext inside the global.asax but is there a workaround or another global.asax method that I can use?

`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ActionFilter to access the posted files before the specified action method:

```
public class ImageModifierAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var files = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Files;
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            var postedFile = files[file];
            if (postedFile == null || postedFile.ContentLength == 0) continue;
            // modify the postedFile Here
        } 
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
[ImageModifier]
public ActionResult ImageUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{ /*.....*/ }
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I need the uploaded file before it gets to the controller beacuse Ninject is started in global.asax. I have a GraphicsHandler object that needs a dependency of HttpPostedFileBase so I really cant wait for the controller